# Replace file with my own version when an external program changes it

Tags: bash, shell-script, ubuntu, files, inotify

I was wondering if anyone knew how to replace a file with my own version when an external program changes it.
My system is running on ubuntu 20.04 Thanks in advance!

Edit for clarity: when Minecraft gets my official username from the servers, auto change the username in the file to a custom one for offline use.

Comment: Yes. But tell us what your goal is. What you describe fills my head with ideas, only I don't exactly know what they are. Too many ideas the first answer I came up with is `inotify` but I see you have tagged with that. So I ask my self, what is the question?

Comment: someone told me that inotify would be a good way to do that, I was hoping someone could lead me to docs/instructions for that or similar

Comment: search for questions with tags [inotify] or [[incron](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/incron/info)]